# when I add a circle it comes like that?

Tags: mesh

[image: the circle isn't a complete one, but only four lines from the center to the border]
I have encountered a problem when adding a circle in blender. the circle appears like that in the image while I in object mode. as you can see it is only for lines not a circular shape. what's the reason for this problem and how can I fix it. is the problem in the software or in my gpu.

Comment: Looks like a drawing issue. Please check that your GPU fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and update your graphics driver.

Comment: How exactly do you add circle? Does it happen with a new file? Try go to File > Defaults > Load Factory

Comment: Edit your question and add more information on the GPU you are using.